# How to remove local storage in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am studying JavaScript and have been stuck on this for weeks! I need to remove these for items from local Storage. But using `localStorage.removeItem('diary');` Will not work.

```
// Make a demo text item
    data =
        "Friday: We arrived to this wonderful guesthouse after a pleasant journey " +
        "and were made most welcome by the proprietor, Mike. Looking forward to " +
        "exploring the area tomorrow.";
    item = makeDiaryItem("text", data);

    // Make a key using a fixed timestamp
    key = "diary" + "1536771000001";

    // Store the item in local storage
    localStorage.setItem(key, item);

    // Make a demo text item
    data =
        "Saturday: After a super breakfast, we took advantage of one of the many " +
        "signed walks nearby. For some of the journey this followed the path of a " +
        "stream to a charming village.";
    item = makeDiaryItem("text", data);

    // Make a key using a fixed timestamp
    key = "diary" + "1536771000002";

    // Store the item in local storage
    localStorage.setItem(key, item);`
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Not looking for a direct answer.

Comment: Probably, you don't have an `diary` key in `localStorage`. Im viewing your code, and you probably have keys like `diary1536771000002`. So, the thing that you need to do is search keys that starts with `diary` and then, remove these.

Comment: Either you keep track of the specific keys you're using (i.e. `diary1536771000001` etc) or you use `localStorage.clear()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify correct `keyname` that you want to remove from the Local Storage.

In your code, you are setting the item in the Local Storage with the keyname "diary1536771000002". BUT, you are trying to remove the item with keyname "diary".

Try this instead:

```js
localStorage.removeItem('diary1536771000002');
```

Comment: Thank you! i've just tried this, if use localStorage.removeItem('diary1536771000002'); and set another one localStorage.removeItem('diary1536771000003'); and so on, one click and it removes them all, is there a way i could create a function so when ever the button is clicked it will remove the correct piece of storage for that diary piece?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove item with the correct key. In your case, the key would be the combination between `diary` and timestamp

It's possibly like this (because I'm seeing you're using that combination with `key` variable)

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

If it does not work, you can inspect your browser to see the proper key of your local storage (right click on your page and select `Inspect` and after that you can look for `Application` tab)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i found the application and its shows the keys as localStorage.removeItem('diary1536771000001'): all the to 4. Trying to find away in which, when i press the delete key it removes that diary pieces information.

Comment: No problem! hope it's useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all local storage items that begin with a prefix (e.g. `"diary"`), you could use a function like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghsAxgCwgJygXigJQgcwFEAPMKAHygAoqBnYNALinrQEsA7fASiwD4oAIwD2wgDYQ4HbgG4AsAChFAMwCuHRMDbCOUNBAC2wgG4QAMsMRwxAZWDC0cfBACSwQ7WoGEKdM3hIqGjczMbCbAAmUADeilBQiDr0UADWECC0zKyc+ADaALpYUAXySgrxyg7UEsBQbEUADDJ1UAA8UGKW1nYOThAAdBJcwMjN9QDU2ACMvLHl8QlJtWkgRZ1WtvaOzv0rVGyycQtsytQrvCu0-WCqtMhU56XxAL6KR4kcyXfCqmIReEZTEVQJBhKdvIF0FhMNgAORqDRaHSwqAAfigEN8GGYdAYWQYOV4mAEmKC-Xc9FxwVKR0qGCoH2SKygYNS6VosyO8RO1G+v3+hhMEAe6W4vHW3S2fX6+kBrncBhFIEO81eCjVKnUmm0ullQosGx623lHgAQiAAAr6ZRsYjUMDW2349hcEJQMKRGJHPWmA2S3rONweJX8Nkgfr0OBoYC0ADqbBGVAdEBtxDFpQ1ZQA9FmoABVWgQRhvBQ+8xdTYBk0GWjmq0p21UWERNhRkCwlU5lloRRlv2V41BmtULMAPRbbazKqAA)

```js
function removeLocalStorageItems (matcher) {
  const keys = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i += 1) {
    const key = localStorage.key(i);
    if (key) keys.push(key);
  }

  const shouldRemove = typeof matcher === 'function' ? matcher : (str) => matcher.test(str);

  for (const key of keys) {
    if (shouldRemove(key)) localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
}

function removeLocalStorageItemsByPrefix (prefix) {
  removeLocalStorageItems(key => key.startsWith(prefix));
}


// Use:

removeLocalStorageItemsByPrefix('diary');
// or
removeLocalStorageItems(/^diary/);
```